# ColdFusion - How to find a string in that's always preceded and followed by certain characters

Tags: coldfusion

Let's say I have a string that is as follows:

> position":1,"type":"row","answer_id":"9541943203"},{"text":"Creating a report or view","visible":true,"position":2,"type":"row","answer_id":"9541943204"},{"text":"Editing a report or view","visible":true,"position":3,"type":"row","answer_id":"9541943205"},{"text":"Saving a report or view","visible":true,"position":4,"type":"row","answer_id":"9541943206"},

How can I get the values of every `answer_id`?

I know the value I want is always preceded by `"answer_id":"` and it's always followed by `"},`.

How do I compile a list of those values?

e.g. 9541943203, 9541943204, 9541943205, 9541943206

**Dump of deserialized JSON:**
[image: CFDump - Deserialized JSON]

Comment: What have you tried? From [your other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089391/coldfusion-json-parsing-issue), looks like you are already aware of JSON (which is exactly what that string is). What happened when you tried derserializing it?

Comment: I can't figure out how to target the specific data I wanted... I thought this might be easier.

Comment: Deserialize and dump it. What does the data structure look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with JSON in ColdFusion (almost) the same way you do in Javascript.

```
<!--- your JSON string here --->
<cfset sourceString = '{ "data": { ... } }'>

<!--- we will add all answer_id to this array --->
<cfset arrayOfAnswerIDs = []>

<!--- in case there went something wrong, we will store the reason in this variable --->
<cfset errorMessage = "">

<cftry>

    <!--- deserialize the JSON to work with for ColdFusion --->
    <cfset sourceJSON = deserializeJSON(sourceString)>

    <!--- validate the structure of the JSON (expected keys, expected types) --->
    <cfif (
        structKeyExists(sourceJSON, "data") and
        isStruct(sourceJSON["data"]) and
        structKeyExists(sourceJSON["data"], "pages") and
        isArray(sourceJSON["data"]["pages"])
    )>

        <!--- iterate pages --->
        <cfloop array="#sourceJSON["data"]["pages"]#" index="page">

            <!--- skip pages that do not contain questions --->
            <cfif (
                (not isStruct(page)) or
                (not structKeyExists(page, "questions")) or
                (not isArray(page["questions"]))
            )>
                <cfcontinue>
            </cfif>

            <!--- iterate questions --->
            <cfloop array="#page["questions"]#" index="question">

                <!--- skip questions that do not have answers --->
                <cfif (
                    (not isStruct(question)) or
                    (not structKeyExists(question, "answers")) or
                    (not isArray(question["answers"]))
                )>
                    <cfcontinue>
                </cfif>

                <!--- iterate answers --->
                <cfloop array="#question["answers"]#" index="answer">

                    <!--- skip invalid answer objects --->
                    <cfif not isStruct(answer)>
                        <cfcontinue>
                    </cfif>

                    <!--- fetch the answer_id --->
                    <cfif (
                        structKeyExists(answer, "answer_id") and
                        isSimpleValue(answer["answer_id"])
                    )>

                        <!--- add the answer_id to the array --->
                        <cfset arrayOfAnswerIDs.add(
                            answer["answer_id"]
                        )>

                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>

            </cfloop>

        </cfloop>

    <cfelse>
        <cfset errorMessage = "Pages missing or invalid in JSON.">
    </cfif>

    <cfcatch type="Application">
        <cfset errorMessage = "Failed to deserialize JSON.">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<!--- show result in HTML --->
<cfoutput>

    <!--- display error if any occured --->
    <cfif len(errorMessage)>
        <p>
            #errorMessage#
        </p>
    </cfif>

    <p>
        Found #arrayLen(arrayOfAnswerIDs)# answers with an ID.
    </p>

    <ol>
        <cfloop array="#arrayOfAnswerIDs#" index="answer_id">
            <li>
                #encodeForHtml(answer_id)#
            </li>
        </cfloop>
    </ol>

</cfoutput>
```

You might want to track all unexpected skips during the processing, so consider having an array of errors instead of a single string.

If you want the answer_id in a list, use
`arrayToList(arrayOfAnswerIDs, ",")`

Comment: This is great!! Thanks for all the help and great notations in the code!!

Comment: I also need to grab the question ID for each set of answers. I have tried this for several days and cannot seem to understand it. Thanks for your help!